# Is it possible to create a thread of a static member function that is defined in a DLL?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, class, dll

Say I have the following .h and .cpp files for a DLL:

---

`.h`

```
#ifdef BLAH_EXPORTS
#define BLAH_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define BLAH_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class BLAH_API MyClass
{
public:
    static void SomeFunction();
};
```

---

`.cpp`

```
#include ".h" //you get the picture

void MyClass::SomeFunction()
{
    //blah blah blah
}
```

---

Now you import the .dll and .lib for this DLL into another program.

**Is it possible to create a thread of MyClass::SomeFunction() since it's hidden in a DLL?**

Comment: Are you using Win32 to create the thread (`CreateThread`) or `std::thread`? For the former, the signature should be something like `static DWORD WINAPI SomeFunction(LPVOID data);` so it has the correct signature and calling convention. Should be fine otherwise, I think.

Comment: Like @StephenLin said, you've got to get the calling convention correct, but otherwise, sure, you can do that.  But what I usually do is just create a small thread function that creates the class object and calls the method.

Comment: I would advise you investigate whether you should be using `CreateThread()` or `_beginthreadex()`, as long as you're going down this road.